# Search in sql database

Tags: sql, database

how to write an sql query to do:
if the parameter is empty then it display all records, but if the parameter is not empty, it display the records for this value?

thank you

Comment: What database engine? With the answers below Joe seems to be assuming SQL Server and Jeffrey Oracle. The optimal answer will differ for different database engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE (YourColumn = @Param OR @Param IS NULL)
```

However, this may not always be an optimal approach. See: [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) for one discussion.

Comment: +1 - Also, @mehdi, please search before asking stuff like this.  About 1000000000 versions of this have been asked and answered already.

Comment: @Barrys answer is the more standard and accepted approach, most modern RDBMS systems support COALESCE, NVL or something similar.

Comment: @Jeffrey: On what are you basing your claim that the other approach is "more standard and accepted?" I've certainly seen the version I've written more often, both in real world code and in blogs like the one I cited. Assuming you're the downvoter, do you think this correct answer really deserves a downvote just because of a variation in syntax?

Comment: @Joe: Fire up TOAD or another Database IDE tool and look at the query cost (cardinality/bytes portion) of your suggestion vs using COALESCE or NVL. The cardinality of your solution is much higher. On a small table I threw together your approach is Cardinality:161 and COALESCE is Cardinality: 17. This can be a performance issue with large databases. Also, in my example, bytes processed were 10% lower with COALESCE vs your method. COALESCE bytes 85 vs your method Bytes: 850

Comment: @Jeffrey: Both versions produce identical execution plans in SQL Server. Also, I mentioned in my answer that this approach may not be optimal and provided a link that discusses the approach in detail.

Comment: @Joe: I never said your query wouldn't work, I just wanted to let OP know that COALESCE is the better option. While execution plans might be the same, the cardinality and bytes processed aren't. (DB has to work harder to find the data). I agree your approach is valid, but why wouldn't we advise someone writing a database procedure to use shorter code and also more performant code?

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
WHERE Column1 = COALESCE(@Param, Column1)
```

Comment: This is the better approach than @Stefanelli

Comment: Better in what sense? If this is for MS SQL Server, neither will perform anything remotely like well. Typically the COALESCE produces table scans and the @var is null or col = @var produces weird plans that use inapproriate index scans and key lookups. On SQL Server 2008 SP2 and above, if OPTION RECOMPILE is used, @var is null or col = @var can perform very well while COALESCE will still table scan (or at best index scan).